# Map Identity Server 4 with another identity provider

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have multiple sites using a custom identity server that allow us to send username and password, so the identity server accept grant type password, the customer asked for sso for the sites, and the current identity provider does not provide login page, so we said that we can implement an identity server 4 to redirect our site and get access token

The problem we need to send back the access token generated by the existing identity provider and not identity server 4

The question is : is there any possibility to map identity server 4 with an external identity provider by default, means, that when user fill email and password, identity server 4 will check credentials with the existing one and get token and send it to the site instead of generating a new token, we think at this to prevent double tokens in our sites

Comment: *when user fill email and password, identity server 4 will check credentials* - I'm confused - where is the user typing in their u/p? Into an Idsrv4 login page or external (eg google) login page?

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, Sites are managed by sitecore, we have two login pages to auth users, by sending login and password to an exisiting idp "SMDP", SMDP support ResourceOwnerPassword, but it does not provid login page to authenticate user, we have to use sitecore FedAuth, so we need to redirect user to login page then give back the token to sitecore instance, the idea is creating is4 and redirect user to login page of is4. so the goal is , when user fill login and password in is4, we need to call SMDP and validate the authentication and get token and refresh token from SMDP and send it to sitecore